# Accessing folder outside user.home is returning false in Linux

Tags: java, linux

I have installed tomcat and deployed a java web application in that in Redhat.

My System property user.home is pointing to /opt/tomcat.

This application tries to access a file path like this

```
 root = new File(rootPath);
    if (!root.isDirectory()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Root is not a directory!");
    }
```

Now i want to access any folder outside /opt like a sibling to /opt, it results false in root.isDirectory(). But if a folder is inside /opt/tomcat then it is properly returning as true.

Both the folders /opt and /nasdata(folder which i want to access) have same permissions.

**UPDATED**

ls -la /opt

```
drwxr-xr-x.  8 root   root   4096 Jul 21 16:15 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 21 root   root   4096 Jul 21 20:53 ..    
drwxr-xr-x  10 tomcat tomcat 4096 Jul 26 21:20 tomcat
```

ls -la /opt/tomcat

```
drwxr-xr-x  10 tomcat tomcat  4096 Jul 26 21:20 .
drwxr-xr-x.  8 root   root    4096 Jul 21 16:15 ..
drwxr-x---   2 tomcat tomcat  4096 Jul 21 16:15 bin
-rw-r-----   1 tomcat tomcat 18949 Jun 28 01:46 BUILDING.txt
drwxr-x---   3 tomcat tomcat  4096 Jul 23 09:20 conf
-rw-r-----   1 tomcat tomcat  6210 Jun 28 01:46 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxr-x---   2 tomcat tomcat  4096 Jul 21 20:14 lib
-rw-r-----   1 tomcat tomcat 57092 Jun 28 01:46 LICENSE
drwxr-x---   2 tomcat tomcat  4096 Jul 28 04:58 logs
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root       9 Jul 26 21:20 nasdata -> /nasdata/
-rw-r-----   1 tomcat tomcat  2333 Jun 28 01:46 NOTICE
drwxr-x---   2 tomcat tomcat  4096 Jul 23 09:20 .oracle_jre_usage
-rw-r-----   1 tomcat tomcat  3372 Jun 28 01:46 README.md
-rw-r-----   1 tomcat tomcat  6898 Jun 28 01:46 RELEASE-NOTES
-rw-r-----   1 tomcat tomcat 16507 Jun 28 01:46 RUNNING.txt
drwxr-x---   2 tomcat tomcat  4096 Jul 23 09:34 temp
drwxr-x---   9 tomcat tomcat  4096 Jul 23 09:37 webapps
drwxr-x---   3 tomcat tomcat  4096 Jul 21 16:28 work
```

ls -la of my root folder. I am trying to access nasdata folder and giving /nasdata as the path.

```
dr-xr-xr-x.  21 root root      4096 Jul 21 20:53 .
dr-xr-xr-x.  21 root root      4096 Jul 21 20:53 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root root         0 Feb  4 20:43 .autorelabel
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root         7 Feb  4 20:39 bin -> usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x.   5 root root      4096 Feb  4 20:52 boot
drwxr-xr-x   19 root root      3220 Jul 21 14:04 dev
drwxr-xr-x.  89 root root      4096 Jul 21 21:00 etc
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root      4096 Feb  4 20:39 home
drwxr-xr-x    3 root root      4096 Jul 21 16:55 home2
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root         7 Feb  4 20:39 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root         9 Feb  4 20:39 lib64 -> usr/lib64
drwxr-xr-x.   5 root root      1024 Jul 21 16:58 localhome
drwx------.   2 root root     16384 Feb  4 20:38 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root      4096 Dec 14  2017 media
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root      4096 Dec 14  2017 mnt
drwxrwxr-x    2 root 9999      4096 Jul 26 16:58 nasdata
drwxr-xr-x.   8 root root      4096 Jul 21 16:15 opt
dr-xr-xr-x  150 root root         0 Jul 21 14:04 proc
dr-xr-x---.   7 root root      4096 Jul 21 16:26 root
drwxr-xr-x   30 root root       980 Jul 21 16:46 run
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root         8 Feb  4 20:39 sbin -> usr/sbin
-rw-r--r--    1 root root 127599309 Jul 21 20:53 sk
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root      4096 Dec 14  2017 srv
dr-xr-xr-x   13 root root         0 Jul 21 14:04 sys
drwxrwxrwt.  14 root root      4096 Jul 28 03:43 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.  14 root root      4096 Jul 21 16:08 usr
drwxr-xr-x.  20 root root      4096 Feb  4 20:46 var
```

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: Can you give an output of the directory structure on the server concerning these items? like `ls -la` showing `/opt` and `/opt/tomcat`? that way we can see what bash sees and can help answer how Java is interpreting

Comment: @GrantLindsey thanks for the reply...updated my post with the results of the ls -la command

Comment: "Now i want to access any folder outside /opt like a sibling to /opt," - how does that match you trying to access /opt/tomcat which is a _child_ of /opt? If you're asking about `/testfolder`, then please show the output of the `ls` command as well and also show the actual value of `rootPath`. Also, did you try a sibling directory to `/opt/tomcat`, e.g. `/opt/testfolder`? Since `/testfolder` is a child to the root it might be the OS that's not allowing your application to access it. Please also show the `ls` command for `/` (we only need to see the results for `opt` and `testfolder`.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the reply...i am trying to access /nasdata folder which is a sibling of /opt folder...actual value of rootPath is /nasdata...i have pasted ls -la of the root folder under which "nasdata" and "opt" folder resides...

Comment: I'm no expert here but notice the `.` after the permissions on `/opt` and the missing of the same on `/nasdata`. For more info, see here: https://superuser.com/questions/230559/what-does-the-dot-mean-at-the-end-of-rw-r-r-how-do-you-set-it-with-chmod

Comment: @Thomas yes noticed that...it relates to SeLinux permissions...but not sure what to make out of it :)...another interesting fact is if i make a softlink to /nasdata from the /opt/tomcat then it works...as can be seen in my post above

Comment: The java.io.File class is very old, and has the unfortunate habit of returning misleading errors (or no errors at all) when many operations fail.  You will find your problem much easier to troubleshoot if you replace all uses of File with the `Path` and `Files` classes of the newer [java.nio.file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package, which returns much more accurate and informative errors when operations fail.